# Conditional/intersection probability lottery card

Tags: probability

A lottery card exchange gives out lottery cards with $32$ digits. Each digit can have only the value $0$ or $1$.

How would I calculate the probability $p$ of $k$ cards succeeding if each of those $k$ cards are chosen randomly without replacement from the set of $2^{32}$ possibilities?

Summary of question (from comment under the answer):

> I have bought k random card numbers (all different from each other), and the lottery company draws 1 card. If that one card drawn by the lottery company corresponds to any of my k cards, then I win. I wish to compute the probability of my winning. (I don't know if this changes the problem.)

I want to get:

$p = P(\text{card 1 succeeds}) + P(\text{card 2 succeeds and card 1 fails}) + \cdots + P(\text{card } k \text{ succeeds and cards } 1 \ldots k - 1 \text{ fails})$

$p = P(\text{card 1 succeeds}) + P(\text{card 2 succeeds} | \text{card 1 fails}) P(\text{card 1 fails}) + \cdots + P(\text{card } k \text{ succeeds} | \text{cards } 1 \ldots k - 1 \text{ fails}) P(\text{cards } 1 \ldots k - 1 \text{ fails})$

I'm trying to get a simple expression of the probability but am not finding the pattern.

The probability theorem:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$

Card 1

$$P(\text{card 1 succeeded}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32}}$$

Card 2

$$P(\text{card 2 succeeded|card 1 failed}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32} - 1}$$

$$P(\text{card 1 failed}) = 1 - P(\text{card 1 succeeded}) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2^{32}} = \dfrac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}}$$

$$P(\text{card 2 succeeded }\cap \text{ card 1 failed}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32} - 1} \cdot \dfrac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}} = \dfrac{1}{2^{32}}$$

Card 3

$$P(\text{card 3 succeeded|cards 1, 2 failed}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32} - 2}$$

$$P(\text{cards 1, 2 failed}) = 1 - P(\text{card 2 succeeded }\cap\text{ card 1 failed})$$
$$= 1 - \dfrac{1}{2^{32}} = \dfrac{2^{32} - 1}{2^{32}}$$

$$P(\text{card 3 succeeded }\cap \text{ cards 1, 2 failed}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32} - 2} \cdot \dfrac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}} = \dfrac{2^{32}-1}{(2^{32}-2)(2^{32})}$$

Card 4

$$P(\text{card 4 succeeded|cards 1, 2, 3 failed}) = \dfrac{1}{2^{32} - 3}$$

$$P(\text{cards 1, 2, 3 failed}) = 1 - P(\text{card 3 succeeded }\cap\text{ cards 1, 2 failed})$$
$$= 1 - \dfrac{2^{32}-1}{(2^{32}-2)(2^{32})} = \dfrac{(2^{32}-2)(2^{32})-(2^{32} - 1)}{(2^{32}-2)(2^{32})}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The answer has been modified after clarifications from the OP.

If $A_i$ is the event that the card $i$ is drawn, then you can perhaps directly use the fact that $P(A_i)=1/2^{32}$. By directly, I mean without using conditional probabilities. The probability of you winning is 
$$
\sum_i P(A_i) = \frac{k}{2^{32}},
$$ since $A_i$s are disjoint.

---

Original answer.
I do not have enough reputation points to comment. The probability of success of card  3 is:
$$
 \mbox{Prob(card $3$ succeeds)}\times \mbox{Prob(card $2$ fails)}\times\mbox{Prob(card $1$ fails)} = \frac{1}{2^{32}-2}\frac{2^{32}-2}{2^{32}-1}\frac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}} = \frac{1}{2^{32}}.
$$
In general, the probability of success of card $i$ is:
$$
\frac{1}{2^{32}}.
$$

And, the probability of winning with $k$ cards is just
$$
\frac{k}{2^{32}},
$$
because the events are disjoint.

Comment: I thought the events are not disjoint. For example, I thought Prob(card 3 succeeds) is influenced by Prob(card 2 fails).

Comment: They are disjoint in the sense that if card $3$ succeeds then card $2$ cannot succeed. Let $A_i$ be the event that card $i$ succeeds, then $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$, for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thanks! So the probability of card $k$ is: Prob(card k succeeds) $\times$ Prob(card $k - 1$ fails) $\times$ $\ldots$ $\times$ Prob(card 1 fails)?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks! Where did I go wrong in my calculations since I wasn't able to get the same pattern of $\frac{k}{2^{32}}$?

Comment: Good question! Now that I think of it, I am not sure where you go wrong. Is it possible for you to "unaccept" the answer? I will think over, and hopefully give you a more convincing answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have bought one card number, and the lottery company draws $k$ cards. If one of the $k$ cards corresponds to yours, then you win. You wish to compute the probability of your winning. Can you confirm this?

Comment: My question was more like: I have bought $k$ random card numbers (all different from each other), and the lottery company draws $1$ card. If that one card drawn by the lottery company corresponds to any of my $k$ cards, then I win. I wish to compute the probability of my winning. (I don't know if this changes the problem.)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. If that is the case, you can perhaps directly use the fact that $P(A_i) = 1/2^{32}$. By directly, I mean without using conditional probabilities. The probability of you winning is $\sum_iP(A_i)$, which is $k/2^{32}$, since $A_i$s are disjoint.

Comment: By "disjoint", do you mean that the $A_{i}$s are "independent"?

Comment: Disjoint means $A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset$. This is the case in your question because only one card can win.

Comment: If you agree and if you are convinced by the new answer, then we should perhaps edit the question and the answer to reflect this by integrating into them the contents of the comments. We can then delete some of the comments since they will not add much to the discussion.

Comment: I've added my summary of the question to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A given card wins with probability $\frac 1{2^{32}}$.  If your $k$ cards are distinct, the events of each one winning are mutually exclusive, so you can add the probabilities.  The chance of one of $k$ cards winning is $\frac k{2^{32}}$.